# AD user is created in the wrong OU

Tags: c#, active-directory

I will create a AD User with C# but the user isn't creating in the right OU!

Every user is created in the users OU in company.lan and not for example in `Users/HR/company.lan`.

My code is:

```
string ouPath = $"OU=Users,OU={selectedDepartment},OU={selectedLocation},DC=vollmer,DC=lan";

string fullPath = $"LDAP://{ouPath}";

using (DirectoryEntry ouEntry = new DirectoryEntry(fullPath))
{
    using (UserPrincipal newUser = new UserPrincipal(context))
    {
        newUser.SamAccountName = username;
        newUser.GivenName = firstName;
        newUser.Surname = lastName;
        newUser.SetPassword(password);
        newUser.Enabled = true;
        newUser.Save();
    }
}
```

In debugging the fullPath locks also right

```
OU=Users,OU=HR,OU=Biberach,DC=company,DC=lan
```

I also try without LDAP:// but it also doesn't work.

Comment: The new user needs to be added to the directory entry:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/add-user-local-system

Comment: Specify the OU dn when constructing your `context` object.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a reference to the OU in `ouEntry`, but then you don't use it. You're instead using `new UserPrincipal(context)` to create the user. Where the user is created will depend on how you defined `context`.

You're mixing use of the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace (i.e. `DirectoryEntry`) with the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace (`UserPrincipal`). I would suggest that you stick to one or the other. So you should either:

1. Get rid of the `DirectoryEntry` reference and change how you define `context` so that it points to the right OU.
2. Don't use `UserPrincipal` and use [`ouEntry.Children.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directoryentries.add) instead.

That could look something like this:

```
var newUser = ouEntry.Children.Add($"CN={username}", "user");
newUser.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = username;
newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = firstName;
newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = lastName;
newUser.Properties["unicodePwd"].Value = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"\"{password}\"");
newUser.CommitChanges();
```

Setting `unicodePwd` will depend on if your connection is encrypted. If you're running this from a computer joined to the same domain, you can use:

```
var ouEntry = new DirectoryEntry(fullPath, null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure | AuthenticationTypes.Sealing);
```

Otherwise, you'd have to use LDAPS (LDAP over SSL) on port 636, which may or may not be more complicated to setup.

```
string fullPath = $"LDAP://vollmer.lan:636/{ouPath}";
var ouEntry = new DirectoryEntry(fullPath);
```